# Bugs appear when moving too fast through a menu I made using Python Turtles

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Ok, so I'm trying to make a menu for a small turtle race game I made earlier this year. The menu mainly consists of different colored (and circular) turtles that do something when you click on them. However, my problem comes when the turtle-buttons transition to a new set of turtle-buttons.

What happens during the transition is that all the turtles come down from where they are to under the screen, get replaced with the new turtle buttons, and then those turtle-buttons drift back up to where they would go in the menu, one at a time.

But, since the buttons go one at a time, you can press a button that would load the transition process while a transition was still going on! And predictably, the program doesn't like that very much. So, how would you go about fixing such a problem? Maybe if there was a way to remotely abort a function from a different function, but I don't know how to do that lol

While I could disable the button or make them wait until the transition's done, I would much rather find a way that allows people to quickly navigate through because I respect their time.[Here's the link to the original Repl](https://replit.com/@MichaelHowell5/a-turtle-menu-for-a-game-that-defiently-doesnt-deserve-it), and the [unfluffed version that highlights my issue can be found here](https://replit.com/@MichaelHowell5/Turtle-Menu-Lite-Lite-Lite-Lite-for-troubleshooting-v12). The functions that I suspect the problem stems from is `introductions`, `resolution`, and take a look at `multibutton` and `create_button` if you want to see how the buttons are created. Please help!

Edit: Since someone told me that Outside links aren't allowed, I'll post the unfluffed code here (don't worry, it's not 450 lines anymore):

```
    # Imports
import turtle
from giant_list_of_all_colors import all_colors, all_shapes
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from tkinter import colorchooser
from time import sleep
import random
from turtle import TurtleGraphicsError
import traceback
# Window properties
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("haha yes")

debug = True

# Making and configuring the canvas inside the window
canvas = turtle.ScrolledCanvas(root)
canvas.config(width= 600, height=400)
# Turtems
t = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
t.hideturtle()
sc = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)

# Pack the canvas into the window
canvas.pack()

# vars
screen_width = sc.window_width()
screen_height = sc.window_height()

negative_max = -(screen_width / 2)
positive_max = -(negative_max)

all_button_turtles = []
all_button_pos = []
all_shapes = ["arrow", "square", "circle", "turtle", "triangle", "classic"]

if debug:
  print('program starting...')

# Core Button Automation/Creation Code
""" 
CREATE_BUTTON:
- Makes a Turtle-based button, complete with text and function binding to onclick(). 
- While it _can_ be used by itself, it's more commonly used by the multibutton function 
- After the creation of the button, it adds position data to all_button_pos (gets deleted in "def introductions") as well as adds the button to all_button_turtles (gets deleted in "def resolutions")
- Don't expect anything else to be this well commented-- I made this part for a school assignment, but then decided to expand upon it more myself... so yeah, sorry about that 
"""

def create_button(button_text, redirect_to_func, color = 'grey', pos = (0,-50), turtle_size = (3,5), font_info = ('Comic Sans MS', 10, 'bold'), text_color = 'purple', shape = 'circle'):
  global all_button_turtles
  turtle_name = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas) # Makes it so whatever name you put in becomes a turtle
  turtle_name.speed(0)
  turtle_name.up()
  turtle_name.hideturtle()
  turtle_name.goto(pos) # Goes to specified pos in arguments
  turtle_name.turtlesize(turtle_size[0], turtle_size[0], turtle_size[1]) #Makes the DIY button bigger
  turtle_name.pencolor(text_color)
  turtle_name.rt(90)
  turtle_name.fd(20 * turtle_size[0])
  turtle_name.write(button_text, True, 'center', font = font_info)
  turtle_name.fillcolor(color) # Changes the color to what you want the color of the button to be
  turtle_name.pencolor('black') # Makes the border along the edge black
  turtle_name.shape(shape) #Makes the button... look like a button (assuming it's a circle)
    
  if debug:
    print(f"The '{color}' button ('{button_text}') is been created and put at {pos[0]}, {pos[1]}!") #debug go brrr
  all_button_turtles.append(turtle_name)
  all_button_pos.append(pos)  
  turtle_name.onclick(redirect_to_func, 1) # Starts up the click listener on left click
  
  return turtle_name # Returns all of this data in case I wanna do something with it later

""" 
MULTIBUTTON:
- It's create_button, but for more buttons!
- It make a bunch of buttons at once, and automatically spaces them out depending on how many buttons you specified for it to make (up to like 8 or so because the canvas is too small to support more)
- It can also automate coloring of text/buttons, like it you want random or a repeating pattern of alternating colors
- A bit outdated, as I think there was a small bug with the color_pick_type parameter that I fixed later. Don't worry-- I swear that's not the cause of my problem!
"""

def multibutton(button_text, button_funcs, button_colors = ['red', 'orange'], y_value = 0, color_pick_type = 'incrimental', text_colors = 'purple', button_shapes = 'circle'):
  
  Button = {num: turtle.Turtle for num in range(len(button_text))}
  
  for new_buttons in range(len(button_text)):

    spacing = (negative_max * (1 / len(button_text) + 1)) - ((new_buttons + 1) * -(screen_width / len(button_text)))

    if isinstance(button_colors, str):
      color = button_colors
    elif color_pick_type == 'random':
      color = random.choice(button_colors)
    elif color_pick_type == 'incrimental':
      color = button_colors[new_buttons % len(button_colors)]
    else:
      msg("Something went wrong", "Color or button_color wasn't assigned correctly!", 3)
      exit()

    if isinstance(text_colors, str):
      text_color = text_colors
    elif color_pick_type == 'random':
      text_color = random.choice(text_colors)
    elif color_pick_type == 'incrimental':
      text_color = text_colors[new_buttons % len(text_colors)]
    else:
      msg("Something went wrong", "Color or text_color wasn't assigned correctly!", 3)
      exit()
    
    if isinstance(button_shapes, str):
      shape = button_shapes
    elif color_pick_type == 'random':
      shape = random.choice(button_shapes)
    elif color_pick_type == 'incrimental':
      shape = button_shapes[new_buttons % len(button_shapes)]
    else:
      msg("Something went wrong", "shape or button_shapes wasn't assigned correctly!", 3)
      exit()
    
    # Running final commands
    try:
      if button_funcs[new_buttons][0]:    
        Button[new_buttons] = create_button(button_text[new_buttons], partial(resolution, button_funcs[new_buttons][1]), color, pos = (spacing, y_value), text_color = text_color, shape = shape)
      elif not button_funcs[new_buttons][0]:
        Button[new_buttons] = create_button(button_text[new_buttons], partial(button_funcs[new_buttons][1]), color, pos = (spacing, y_value), text_color = text_color, shape = shape)
  
    except TypeError:
        Button[new_buttons] = create_button(button_text[new_buttons], partial(resolution, button_funcs[new_buttons]), color, pos = (spacing, y_value), text_color = text_color, shape = shape)
    if debug:
      print("Multibutton Job's done :p")

# Scene Transitioners
"""
INTRODUCTIONS:
- The problem child and where all the errors are stemming from 
- Essentially handles moving the buttons up to their proper places while making it look prettier than just having the buttons teleport to where they need to go
- Deletes all saved button positions in 'all_button_pos' after its done running, as I don't need them anymore (does this near the very end) 
- Also handles making the title and subtitles... by forwarding it to an entirely different function later down the line (create_titlescreen) 
"""
def introductions(title, *subtitle):
  global all_button_turtles
  if debug:
    print(f"moving ({len(all_button_turtles)}) button(s) up")
  create_titlescreen(title, subtitle)
  for turtems in all_button_turtles:
    turtems.up()
    try:
      turtems.goto(all_button_pos[(all_button_turtles.index(turtems))][0], -(screen_height))
    except IndexError as ie:
      print("\n\nAAHHH NOOOO IT FAILEDDD D:")
      print(f"All called turtles ({len(all_button_turtles)}):{all_button_turtles}")
      print(f"All called turtle's positions ({len(all_button_pos)}): {all_button_pos}")
      print(f"ONE-LINER ERROR: {ie}")
      print(f"TRACEBACK:")
      traceback.print_exc()
      exit()
    if debug:
      print(f"TURTEM POS ({all_button_turtles.index(turtems) + 1}): {turtems.pos()}")
    turtems.showturtle()
    turtems.seth(270)
    turtems.speed(3)
    turtems.goto(all_button_pos[(all_button_turtles.index(turtems))])
    if debug:
      try:
        print(f"FINAL TURTEM POS ({all_button_turtles.index(turtems) + 1}): {turtems.pos()}")
      except ValueError as ve:
        print("\n\nAAHHH NOOOO IT FAILEDDD... but for a different reason???")
        print(f"All called turtles ({len(all_button_turtles)}):{all_button_turtles}")
        print(f"All called turtle's positions ({len(all_button_pos)}): {all_button_pos}")
        print(f"ONE-LINER ERROR: {ve}")
        print(f"TRACEBACK:")
        traceback.print_exc()
        exit()
  del all_button_pos[:]
"""
RESOLUTION:
- Does the same thing as 'introductions', but backwards!
- Moves buttons down in preparation for deletion offscreen
- Not only does this handle deleting the buttons/text, but it also clears "all_turtle_buttons", the program's ONLY way of telling what button turtles are currently in play
"""   
def resolution(func, x = None, y = None, *args):
  global all_button_turtles
  temp_turtles = all_button_turtles.copy()
  del all_button_turtles[:]
  for turtems in temp_turtles:
    turtems.onclick(None)
  t.clear()
  if not debug:
    print(f"THE GREAT RESOLUTION ({len(temp_turtles)})")
  for turtem in temp_turtles:
    turtem.clear()
    turtem.speed(3)
    turtem.up()
    turtem.seth(90)
    turtem.fd(abs(turtem.xcor()) - screen_height)
    turtem.hideturtle()
  del temp_turtles
  if debug:
    print(f"The following number should be 0... and if it's not, then we have some problems: {len(all_button_turtles)}")
  func(args)

"""
CREATE_TITLESCREEN:
- Handles making the title/subtitles at the start of every scene
- Accepts only 1 title parameter, but as many subtitle parameters as your heart's desires
- the "size" parameter controls the size of the big title, then half of size makes the font size for the subtitles 
- For every new argument for a subtitle, it acts like you just did a \n and makes a new line
""" 
def create_titlescreen(title, subtitles, size = 23):
  t.speed(69) # haha funny number
  t.home()
  t.seth(90)
  t.clear()
  t.up()
  t.goto(0, screen_height / 3)
  t.write(title, align= "center", font=("Comic Sans MS", size, "bold"))
  if len(subtitles) != 0:
    for txt in subtitles:  
      t.bk(size / 2)
      t.write(str(txt), align = 'center')
  t.home()
  t.hideturtle()
  t.down()

# GUI messaging
"""
MSG:
- There used to be other functions here (user-input popups like bool, num, and str), but I removed them for the sake of simplicity
- Pretty much self-explanitory; the function uses 'tk.messagebox' to make a popup that the user has to read before moving on. I probably didn't _have_ to make this (probably REALLY redundant), but I got sick of typing the entire thing out 
-  Like with the original messagebox function, the first 2 parameters make the title of the popup as well as its contents, respectively
- However, the last perameter (type) handles what _type_ of messagebox is shown to the user, with the higher the number, the more severe the message will be (normal, then warning, then error)
- Any type argument higher than 3 or less than 1 will error out
"""
def msg(title, prompt, type = 1, *args):
  if type == 1:
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(title, prompt)
  elif type == 2:
    tk.messagebox.showwarning(title, prompt)
  elif type == 3:
    tk.messagebox.showerror(title, prompt)
  else:
    tk.messagebox.showerror("Either your or my code sucks", "Whatever number you put into msg() was not recognized!")

# Screen5 Button Code (all of it got removed)
def receive_shape(player, x, y):
  msg("(Un)successfully applied!", "I literally deleted everything in here :)")
  if player == 1:
    resolution(screen5A)
  else:
    resolution(screen5B)

def choose_color(turtle,player,*gonna):
  msg("I cut out all the content here", "To help isolate my problem, I took out all the code here")

def shape_scene(player, x, y):
  multibutton(
    [all_shapes[0], all_shapes[1], all_shapes[2], all_shapes[3], all_shapes[4], all_shapes[5]],
              [
               [False, partial(receive_shape, player)],
               [False, partial(receive_shape, player)],
               [False, partial(receive_shape, player)],
               [False, partial(receive_shape, player)],
               [False, partial(receive_shape, player)],
               [False, partial(receive_shape, player)]
              ],
              
              button_colors = 'black', button_shapes = all_shapes)
  introductions("test3: Shape Scene", "If you tried to go here before the menus were done loading, it shouldn't have crashed.", "Probably because the previous menu had the same # of buttons in the same place.", "Might be worth looking into all_buttons_pos?")

def convert_dice():
  msg("I cut out all the content here", "To help isolate my problem, I took out all the code here")
def choose_dice(*you):
  msg("I cut out all the content here", "To help isolate my problem, I took out all the code here")

def choose_key(*down):  
  msg("I cut out all the content here", "To help isolate my problem, I took out all the code here")
def choose_headstart(*never):
  msg("I cut out all the content here", "To help isolate my problem, I took out all the code here")

def back_to_menu(x, y):
  resolution(screen2)

# Actual Scene code:
def screen2(gonna):
  button_colors = ['red', 'orange', 'red']
  sc.onscreenclick(None, 3)
  sc.onscreenclick(None, 2)
  multibutton(['Player 1', 'Player 2', 'back to title'], [screen5A, screen5B, titlescreen], button_colors = button_colors)
  introductions("Player Select", "Choose a button and do it quick! Don't let the buttons reach their place!!!")
def screen5A(never):
  multibutton(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E?", "Leave"],
             [
               [False, choose_color],
               partial(shape_scene, 1, None),
               [False, choose_key],
               [False, choose_dice],
               [False, choose_headstart],
               [False, back_to_menu]
             ], button_colors = [random.choice(list(all_colors.keys())) for r in range(6)], text_colors = [random.choice(list(all_colors.keys())) for r in range(6)])
  introductions("Player 1", "most of these buttons don't do anything lol", "Button B leads to another menu. Click ASAP!")
def screen5B(*never):
  multibutton(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E?", "Leave"],
             [
               [False, choose_color],
               partial(shape_scene, 2, None),
               [False, choose_key],
               [False, choose_dice],
               [False, choose_headstart],
               [False, back_to_menu]
             ], button_colors = [random.choice(list(all_colors.keys())) for r in range(6)], text_colors = [random.choice(list(all_colors.keys())) for r in range(6)])  
  introductions("Player 2", "most of these buttons don't do anything lol", "Button B leads to another menu. Click while the transition's still going on!")

def to_screen2(*you):
  msg("Before you continue...", "The bug in question happens when you go through the menus too fast! Try blitzing through the next menu before all the buttons come up, and watch the console while ding it!")
  msg("One more thing...", "Different things happen depending on if debug mode is on! With it off, it crashes due to an IndexError. With it on, it's just a ValueError. Give each one a shot later!")
  resolution(screen2)

def titlescreen(*give):
  hi = create_button('Press da big red button to start the bad code :)', to_screen2, 'firebrick', turtle_size = (5, 7), text_color = 'purple')
  introductions("Turtems; Problematic Build", "haha no")
  
"""RUNTIME CODE"""
titlescreen(None)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Edit2: And I forgot that you're going to need this in a separate file in order to run this code. It used to have all the colors (there were so many that I had to make a separate Python program just to convert them all into dictionary variables), but I ran out of word limit to post all of them, so just make do with this:

```
all_colors = {'yellow': [255, 255, 0], 'green': [0, 255, 0], 'red': [255, 0, 0], 'blue': [0, 255, 0], 'orange': [255, 165, 0], 'purple': [160, 32, 240], 'violet': [238, 130, 238]}
all_shapes = ["arrow", "square", "circle", "turtle", "triangle", "classic"]
```

Be sure to save those 2 lines in a **separate file** called `giant_list_of_all_colors.py`! I definitely should have made this a text file, so sorry about that . If you want the full-color list for whatever reason, look at any of the 2 Repls I liked above. There should be the entire list there if you're interested

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions should be self-contained. No links to other sites. Also, the code should be a [mre]. The 900 (or even the 450) lines you have are not that. Help us help you; try to narrow down where the problem might be happening. Also, search for tutorials on how to debug Python code. It's a skill you won't regret having.

Comment: Ok, I cut my code down as much as I could (it's now like half its original size) and added some stuff to help with troubleshooting. However, it's still a bit long (like 200 lines). I can still repost the here, but it might be unsightly. Are you OK with that? Thanks again for responding! I've been trying to get help for a while now and no one would give me the time of day to even comment on my posts until now

Comment: And I just finished re-uploading my code so it's all on this website now (you don't need the external links anymore). Take a look!

Comment: Ok, and I also edited the main post because I forgot to add the giant_list_of_all_colors.py file's contents. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

There's still a lot of code there, but my guess is it's a multitasking synchronization issue ("race condition") with the `all_button_turtles` list. For example, the event handler is called to animate the buttons on. Then, one button is clicked right away and the event handler to animate them off is called. So you have 2 handlers running at the same time. One is reading the list and the other is modifying it, simultaneously. Thats' a problem.

There are a few solutions. I think OOP can help you here. Create (at least) 2 classes: `Screen` and `Button`. Each `Screen` object would have it's own list of buttons. And each `Button` object contains its own positional information. If you are not familiar with classes in Python, you could maybe just have multiple lists of buttons. One for each screen.

The goal is to not have the global `all_button_turtles` and `all_button_pos` lists. Or, at least use synchronization techniques to ensure there is no race condition. This option will be more complex than multiples lists or classes.